# 90s or 2000 techno song with piano introduction (no vocals)

Tags: electronic-music, instrumental, piano, techno

Looking for a techno song/eletronic I believe it's from the 90's almost 2000. Starts with a single note from the piano and the introduction goes by this way. Beautiful and calm and it has a little echo at the end of the notes.
Then comes others components etc. The chorus is exactly like the piano's introduction.
The entire music is only instrumental, have no vocals at all and was a success.
Already listened to a several lists of this kind a song but couldn't find it. 
I'm obsessed lol somebody please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Children](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwqmJilXxJY) by Robert Miles?

It's hard to tell from your description alone, frankly.